# Radio Button that show saved selected option, with Python Bootstrap

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I'm pretty new with Python Bootstrap, and I created a Python Bootstrap Form with Radio Button options for a specific field **entrepot.etage**
I am wondering what is the best way to show which option is checked, on saved database record ?
Like if "Option 2" is saved on my record, I want it checked when you edit or view with Radio Button.

There is my HTML file (Just the important part)

```
<form action="/entrepots/edit_entrepot" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="control-label">Étage : </label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="radio-etage">
                        <input type="radio" name="etage" value="1">1
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-etage">
                        <input type="radio" name="etage" value="2">2
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ entrepot.id }}" name="id">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" value="Modifier Entrepots">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use `{% if entrepot.myfieldvalue == value %}checked{% endif %}` in the radio input. If you do not need it to be edited, you can include `disabled`

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try.  Thanks